# How to create empty closure properly?

Tags: swift, syntax, closures

I have a class with a closure as a property:

```
class MyClass{
     var onChange = {}

     func foo(){
         onChange()
     }
}
```

A behaviour implemented in closure is used in method `foo`:

```
var c = MyClass()
c.onChange = {
    println("something is changed");
}
c.foo()  // prints 'something is changed'
```

It's easy to make closures with an argument like `{(n: Int) -> Void in println(n); }` but how to create a closure without input arguments?

I tried to use `{}`, `{in}`, etc., but it gave a compilation error.

How to create empty closure properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use:

```
var closure = {() -> () in
    return
}
```

Comment: Oh, It seems {() -> () in} and {() -> Void in} also correct. Your answer helped me in any way)

Comment: Void and () are same for swift.

Answer (score -1):

// Type

typealias EmptyClosure = () -> Void

// Setting Value

var tryAgain: EmptyClosure?

// Usage on a click method

func onClickButton() {
tryAgain?()
}

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the question. This isn't an "empty" (do nothing) closure. It's a Void-returning closure property.